# How to compute the following recurrence relations

Tags: algorithm, recursion, runtime

`T(n) = cT(n^(0.5)) + n`? where `c` is a constant `c>0`.

I've tried everything but could not find a solution.
Any help is welcome, thanks.

Comment: Algorithms assignment?

Comment: I cant use master theorem since c is not greater than 1.

Comment: Just curious, can you tell me in what algorithm will generate a recurrence which makes c < 1, as it means the sub-problem number is smaller than 1...?

Comment: If it helps, T(n) = sum[i>=0] (c^i * n^(1/2^i)). Now you have to find the sum of this infinite sequence...

Answer (score 1):

It is linear.

Assume there is some `K` such that `T(n) <= Kn` for all `n < M`

Then `T(M) <= cKsqrt(M) + M <= KM`

for sufficiently large `K (and M)`, this is true.

`So T(n) = O(n)`.

It is clear that `T(n) = Omega(n)`.

So `T(n) = Theta(n)`.